# Link two Views in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, development

I have a custom list. This list contains questions that have been asked by internal staff members. I have one list view displaying the sender and the question.

I would like that when the row is clicked, it will display the information in an edit view on the same page, just below the list. I could do this in ASP.Net, I am wondering how it could be done using SharePoint Controls only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a conventional list and added an edit button for that purpose.